# How do I map a List of Maps in Hibernate using annotations?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm trying to map a List of Maps into a class using Hibernate annotations.

I'd like my final class to look something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    private List<Map<String, Trip>> trips; 
}
```

The Trip table has a trip number and multiple rows for each trip with the state the trip traveled through.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRIP")
public class Trip {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Person person;

    @Column(name = "TRIP_NO")
    private int trip_no;

    @Column(name = "STATE")
    private String state;

    ...
}
```

So the TRIP table has these columns:

```
Name         Type
ID           NUMBER(9)
PERSON_ID    NUMBER(9)
TRIP_NO      LONG
STATE        VARCHAR2(16)
.
.
.

ID  PERSON_ID  TRIP_NO  STATE ...
1   1          1        MN    ...
2   1          1        WI    ...
3   1          2        ND    ...
4   1          2        MT    ...
5   2          1        IA    ...
```

So in the List of Maps, the TRIP_NO is the index of the List, and the STATE is the key to the Map. Person 1 took 2 trips, the first was to Minnesota and Wisconsin, the second trip to North Dakota and Montana. Person 2 took 1 trip to Iowa.

I'm having trouble navigating through to find how to specify this configuration.

Second question: Can it be done without JPA 2?

Comment: The `@OneToMany` annotation and friends describe relationships between database entities. I'm having trouble identifying what entity the `Map<String, Trip>` would be.

Comment: Map<String, Trip> is mapping a set of trip data keyed by state. So the map will contain all of the trips with the same TRIP_NO and person keyed by the states the trip was in. So, `person1.getTrips().get(1) is {{"MN", tripdata1},{"WI", tripdata2}}`.
`person1.getTrips().get(2) is {{"ND", tripdata1}, {"MT", tripdata2}}`.
`person2.getTrips().get(1) is {{"IA", tripdata1}}`.

Comment: Ah I see. There is too much information in your TRIP table then. It contains both trips and trip destination entities. See my posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach:

```
// composite primary key
public class TripId implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private long trip_no;

    public TripId(int id, long trip_no) {
        this.id = id;
        this.trip_no = trip_no;
    }

    // getters, setters, hashCode, equals
}
```

**EDIT**: I had to update the entity model after Welshbard's questions from the comments below. Changes are:

- `Person` entity: `Map<String, Trip> trips;` replaced by `List<Trip> trips;`
- `Trip` entity: `String state;` field added as the replacement for `trips` key from `Person` entity
- constructors / setters / code snippet for populating data / output schema were updated accordingly

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Trip> trips;

    public Person() {
        this.trips = new List<>();
    }

    public void setTrips(List<Trip> trips) {
        this.trips = trips;
    }

    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
@IdClass(TripId.class)
public class Trip {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Id
    private long trip_no;

    private String state;

    @ManyToOne
    private Person person;

    public Trip() {

    }

    public Trip(String state, long trip_no, Person person) {
        this.state = state;
        this.trip_no = trip_no;
        this.person = person;
    }

    ...
}
```

We can now make use of the above ORM and populate some data:

```
Person person1 = new Person();
Person person2 = new Person();

Trip mn1Trip1 = new Trip("MN", 1, person1);
Trip wi1Trip1 = new Trip("WI", 1, person1);
Trip nd2Trip1 = new Trip("ND", 2, person1);
Trip mt2Trip1 = new Trip("MT", 2, person1);
Trip ia1Trip2 = new Trip("IA", 1, person2);
// more than one trip by a person goes to the same state
Trip mn2Trip1 = new Trip("MN", 2, person1);
Trip ia2Trip2 = new Trip("IA", 2, person2);
Trip mn1Trip2 = new Trip("MN", 1, person2);

person1.setTrips(Arrays.asList(mn1Trip1, wi1Trip1, nd2Trip1, mt2Trip1, mn2Trip1));
person2.setTrips(Arrays.asList(ia1Trip2, ia2Trip2, mn1Trip2));

em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(person1);
em.persist(person2);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Finally, we can query the database to see the schema and how the data were populated:

```
Person table
============
id
--
 1
 7

Trip table
===========
id trip_no person_id state
-- ------- --------- -----
  9       2 IA            7
  4       2 ND            1
  8       1 IA            7
  6       2 MN            1
  2       1 MN            1
 10       1 MN            7
  3       1 WI            1
  5       2 MT            1
```

NOTE: ids are different but the schema was created properly and the data were populated as expected.

As for the questions from the comment below:

```java
// Person class have only trips associated with that person
String jpql1 = "SELECT p.trips FROM Person p WHERE p.id = 1";
List<Trip> trips = em.createQuery(jpql1, Trip.class)
                     .getResultList();

// the code can look at the Trips to find out the trip_no
String jpql2 = "SELECT t.trip_no FROM Trip t JOIN Person p " +
               "WHERE p.id = :id AND t.state = :state";
List<Long> trip_nos = em.createQuery(jpql2, Long.class)
                        .setParameter("id", 1)
                        .setParameter("state", "MN")
                        .getResultList();
```

---

Regarding the second question:

> Can it be done without JPA 2?

You could try with plain old JDBC and use `java.sql.Statement` to insert SQL statements.

Comment: Using a TripId matches the database schema but not the collection mapping that the OP wants. The OP wants to map `List<Map<String, Trip>>` which is impossible.

Comment: Will the Map in the Person class have only trips associated with that person? And the code can look at the Trips to find out the trip_no? What if more than one trip by a person goes to the same state?

Comment: @mpkorstanje: It's impossible. I totally agree. That's why we are trying to provide an entity model that at least fits into Welshbard's schema, aren't we?

Comment: @Welshbard: Now I see your point. To meet all the conditions I have had to change my approach a little (the entity model has been simplified incidentally). Answers to your above questions are placed along with the updated code snippets (you can easily find the `trip_no` it just depends on the query's input criteria).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because didn't test and haven't experienced exactly same thing before but I think using a `List` of `Map<K,V>`s for associative field would be a little complicated, you can have a `Many-to-One` rel for `person` in the `Trip` entity and then a `One-to-Many` for `Trips` in person entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRIP")
public class Trip {    
    /*
    code
    */
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Person person;

    /*
    code
    */
}
```

and in `Person` Entity don't use `List<Map<String, Trip>>` instead of it use **@MapKey** annotation for `Map<String, Trip>`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    @MapKey(name = "state")
    private Map<String, Trip> trips; 
}
```

However you need to review more, I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: How is the TRIP_NO, which is not unique, handled to make the list? Or do I have to @PostLoad to process the Map to get a list of Trip Maps? Let me add a little to the Question to make this clearer.

Comment: What if more than one trip by a person goes to the same state?

Comment: oh, I'm really sorry for delay in responding to your comments, I haven't came on Stackoverflow for some days. your scenario is a little bit complicated and needs to more review, I apologize for currently haven't focuse and time(mybe a few days later), I hope you'll get it fixed soon, you can also edit or complete my answer if was useful, good luck

Answer (score 0):

Unless you alter your database schema what you want is not possible. Notice how the Hibernate documentation omits the collection type as valid content for a collection.

> Naturally Hibernate also allows to persist collections. These
>   persistent collections can contain almost any other Hibernate type,
>   including: basic types, custom types, components and references to
>   other entities.
>   [From Hibernate Collection Mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-mapping)

You can't do this with hibernate because your database design is wonky. Basically your TRIP table has too much information in it as it stores both trips and destinations.

Ideally you have a Trip and Destination.

The Trip consisting of an id, a person_id and a trip_no for the ordering in the list through `@OrderBy`.

The Destinations consist of an id, a trip_id, the state_id for use by the `@MapKey` and the other information for the destination.

Java code would be something like this. Didn't check for any errors. Just to give you the idea.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    @OrderBy(clause=trip_no)
    private List<Trip> trips; 
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRIP")
public class Trip {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Person person;

    @Column(name = "TRIP_NO")
    private int trip_no;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "trip")
    @MapKey(name = "state")
    private Map<String,Destination> destinations
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "DESTINATION")
public class Destination {

    private Trip trip;

    @Column(name = "STATE")
    private String state;

    ...
}
```